# Unable to open 7z-Archive: Open ERROR: Can not open the file as [7z] archive

Tags: fedora, data-recovery, archive, 7z, p7zip

I'm trying to open a 7z-File which I've packed with my phone using the ZArchiver app. Probably the process was interrupted and some files have gone missing, but that's not a huge problem.

Ark and file-roller can't open it.

```
[qohelet@localhost che]$ 7z e Cambulera.7z 

7-Zip [64] 16.02 : Copyright (c) 1999-2016 Igor Pavlov : 2016-05-21
p7zip Version 16.02 (locale=de_AT.UTF-8,Utf16=on,HugeFiles=on,64 bits,8 CPUs Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-4710MQ CPU @ 2.50GHz (306C3),ASM,AES-NI)

Scanning the drive for archives:
1 file, 1400666544 bytes (1336 MiB)

Extracting archive: Cambulera.7z
ERROR: Cambulera.7z
Cambulera.7z
Open ERROR: Can not open the file as [7z] archive


ERRORS:
Is not archive

Can't open as archive: 1
Files: 0
Size:       0
Compressed: 0
```

This is not working either:

```
[qohelet@localhost che]$ 7z e -so Cambulera.7z > raw
ERROR: Cambulera.7z
Cambulera.7z
Open ERROR: Can not open the file as [7z] archive


ERRORS:
Is not archive
```

I've found on https://www.7-zip.org/recover.html some basic 7z-recovery hints, but it's not helpful. Opening it with a hex-editor is giving me the exact output as expected:
[image: Hex-Values]

I wonder it's so difficult. Most archive-formats are relatively robust?
I'm using Fedora.

EDIT 1:

```
Das Paket p7zip-plugins-16.02-13.fc29.x86_64 ist bereits installiert.
Abhängigkeiten sind aufgelöst.
Nichts zu tun.
Fertig.
[qohelet@localhost che]$ 7z t Cambulera.7z

7-Zip [64] 16.02 : Copyright (c) 1999-2016 Igor Pavlov : 2016-05-21
p7zip Version 16.02 (locale=de_AT.UTF-8,Utf16=on,HugeFiles=on,64 bits,8 CPUs Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-4710MQ CPU @ 2.50GHz (306C3),ASM,AES-NI)

Scanning the drive for archives:
1 file, 1400666544 bytes (1336 MiB)

Testing archive: Cambulera.7z
ERROR: Cambulera.7z
Cambulera.7z
Open ERROR: Can not open the file as [7z] archive


ERRORS:
Is not archive

Can't open as archive: 1
Files: 0
Size:       0
Compressed: 0
[qohelet@localhost che]$ 7z l Cambulera.7z

7-Zip [64] 16.02 : Copyright (c) 1999-2016 Igor Pavlov : 2016-05-21
p7zip Version 16.02 (locale=de_AT.UTF-8,Utf16=on,HugeFiles=on,64 bits,8 CPUs Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-4710MQ CPU @ 2.50GHz (306C3),ASM,AES-NI)

Scanning the drive for archives:
1 file, 1400666544 bytes (1336 MiB)

Listing archive: Cambulera.7z


ERROR: Cambulera.7z : Cambulera.7z
Open ERROR: Can not open the file as [7z] archive


ERRORS:
Is not archive


Errors: 1
```

Comment: Looks like 7-zip support is weak outside of Windows. 1. Try a few [alternatives](https://alternativeto.net/software/7-zip/?platform=linux) and lets see what shows up. https://alternativeto.net/software/7-zip/?platform=linux 2. 7z t Cambulera.7z #*Test archive*
3. 7z l Cambulera.7z #*List content*
4. dnf install p7zip-plugins #*Missing plugins* Could it be password protected?

Comment: I'm pretty sure it is password protected. But also the app can't open it any more

Comment: @Czar - edited your recommendation. No changes